# equal *population* variances in paired t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, variance, t-test, paired-data

I I want to perform a paired t-test to check if there's some effect, I have the distribution of "before" and the distribution of "after" the manipulation. Do I need to assume the population variances of the two distribution are equal ?

Comment: The paired t-test is a t-test applied to the differences, so the distribution of the differences is what matters.

Answer (score 8):

Any assumptions you make in a paired test would have to do with the paired differences. After all, a paired test is a one-sample test in disguise.

Therefore, **NO**, you do not need to assume equal variances of the two groups for a paired t-test.

Comment: The paired $t$-test considers whether the mean has changed: it cannot spot whether or not the variance has changed.